# How to configure launch.json in Visual Studio Code? --path variable not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, godot

I'm trying to launch Godot from Visual Studio Code

I can launch Godot fine form the command line using this command:

```
/Applications/godot-3.3.2-stable/bin/godot.osx.tools.x86_64 --path /Users/admin/Documents/Demeria/project/ blocky_game/blocky_game.tscn
```

However, when I try to copy that command into the launch.json file it fails to work because it seems to ignore the --path argument and fail to find the files it needs.

This is my launch.json file:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            //"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/godot.osx.tools.x86_64",
            "program": "/Applications/godot-3.3.2-stable/bin/godot.osx.tools.x86_64",
            "args": [
                "-v",
                "--path /Users/admin/Documents/Demeria/project/",
                "/Users/admin/Documents/Demeria/project/blocky_game/blocky_game.tscn",
                
                
            ],
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "/Users/admin/Documents/Demeria/project/",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "visualizerFile": "${workspaceFolder}/modules/voxel/voxel.natvis",
            "osx": {
                "MIMode": "lldb"
```

Does anyone know how to make it work with the --path variable?

Comment: you need to pass `--path` and `/Users/admin/Documents/Demeria/project/` as separate arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate --path from its argument like this:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(lldb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        //"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/godot.osx.tools.x86_64",
        "program": "/Applications/godot-3.3.2-stable/bin/godot.osx.tools.x86_64",
        "args": [
            "-v",
            "--path",
            "/Users/admin/Documents/Demeria/project/",
            "/Users/admin/Documents/Demeria/project/blocky_game/blocky_game.tscn",
            
        ],
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "/Users/admin/Documents/Demeria/project/",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "lldb",
        "visualizerFile": "${workspaceFolder}/modules/voxel/voxel.natvis",
        "osx": {
            "MIMode": "lldb"
```